# IE 10 scrollbar and form buttons look like wingding font characters

Tags: scrollbar, internet-explorer-10, wingdings

I first saw this when I tried the IE 10 beta a while back and thought that it would be resolved in the full release. Not so. I've tried uninstalling all the way back to version IE8. The wingding buttons problem only show up when I have IE 10 installed.

About Me:
Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit
Graphics Chipset    ATI Radeon HD 3800 Series

Comment: There is no way we can reproduce this issue. Do you have a test case?

Comment: Pardon the delayed post. The issue was a corrupted Segoe UI fontset

Answer (score 0):

The IE 10 scrollbar and form interfaces use the "Segoe UI" font-family which includes **Symbol**, Regular, Bold, SemiBold. Once installed all "text-based" anomalies in the interface buttons correct themselves including the forms, and IE10 scrollbar up/down buttons.

The font is normally part of the default fonts installed in Windows 7. For some reason the beta-IE must have corrupted the font-set. Fortunately I was able to copy the fonts from another computer running windows 7.